# Открытие гиперссылки при выполнении условия. js

Tags: javascript, frontend

Если пользователь ввел верный логин и пароль, нужно перебросить его на сайт, ссылку можно подставить любую, пробовал через метод "document.location.href" но браузер выдает ошибку.

```
function alerted() {

  let a = document.querySelector(".lf--input").value;
  let b = document.querySelector(".lf--input2").value;
  if (a === "login" && b === "123"){
  document.location.href = "https://google.com/";
    //открыть гиперссылку
  }
```

Comment: лучше в вопрос сразу добавлять какую ошибку выдает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет `window.location = 'https://google.com/'` [как это работает?](https://javascript.ru/window-location)

Answer (score 0):

в функции alerted фигурные скобки не закрыл

Comment: закрыл, там просто есть еще кусок else, не стал его вставлять в вопрос.

Comment: @alex А какую ошибку то браузер выдает?: